# Python BeautifulSoup, how to change the drop down and get html?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

In my HTML I have the follow obtions:

```
<div class="si-dropdown dropdown-mode-grid w-50 w-xs-30 w-md-auto">
<ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-dre-grid">
<li><a data-type="0" role="button">ANUAL</a></li>
<li><a data-type="1" role="button">TRIMESTRAL</a></li>
<li><a data-type="2" role="button">YEAR TO DATE</a></li>
<li class="optgroup" tabindex="0"><label class="d-block pt-1 fs-2 grey-text pl-1">VISÃO POR TRIMESTRE</label></li>
<li><a data-type="3" role="button">1º trimestre</a></li>
<li><a data-type="4" role="button">2º trimestre</a></li>
<li><a data-type="5" role="button">3º trimestre</a></li>
<li><a data-type="6" role="button">4º trimestre</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-xsmall dropdown-trigger d-flex justify-around" data-target="dropdown-dre-grid" href="#!">
<span>ANUAL</span><i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
</a>
</div>
```

The default is ANUAL, and when I change, other data appear but the URL doesn't change

is there any way to get this new data without using SELENIUM?

I using the following code to get the HTML

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = f"""https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/movi3"""
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: how are you changine the ANUAL

Comment: `F12` on your browser, `network` tab and filter `xhr` requests: `https://statusinvest.com.br/acao/getdre?companyName=movida&type=1`, `type=2`....

Comment: Thanks Pedro Lobito! where did you find this URL?

Comment: @FábioMinutti i think Pedro were clear enough on his answer, read it once more.